# Using random string value to update all rows in a column for testing purposes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following SQL to create my random `varchar` using the user-defined function of `generateString()`.

```
CREATE VIEW rndView
AS
    SELECT RAND() rndResult
GO

CREATE FUNCTION RandFn()
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,18)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rndValue DECIMAL(18,18)

    SELECT @rndValue = rndResult
    FROM rndView

    RETURN @rndValue
END
GO

ALTER FUNCTION generateString() 
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @exclude varchar(50)
    SET @exclude = '0:;<=>?@O[]`^\/'

    DECLARE @char char
    DECLARE @len char
    DECLARE @output varchar(50)

    SET @output = ''
    SET @len = 8

    DECLARE @random DECIMAL(18,18) = (SELECT dbo.RandFn())

    while @len > 0 begin
        select @char = char(round(@random * 74 + 48, 0))

        if charindex(@char, @exclude) = 0 begin
            set @output = @output + @char
            set @len = @len - 1
        end
    end

    RETURN @output
END
```

However, when attempting to use this function in the `UPDATE` clause below, the query never finishes. I have less than 100 records. The goal is to get random `varchar` data into all rows on a specific column in a table...

```
UPDATE dbo.Inci
SET SerialText = dbo.generateString()
```

Comment: Do you have any restrictions in random `varchar` data like it should be 8 character or it should have one symbol atleast anything like that ?

Comment: No, I just need random varchar data in the field. Everything right now is NULL in the column and isn't suitable for testing.

Comment: Then just use `Newid()`. Something like this `UPDATE dbo.Inci
SET SerialText = newid()`

Comment: That does work. Thank you. Though, I am still curious as to how to get the  original post's statement to work in the event that I need specific or more 'realistic' data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `@char` is having one of exclude characters ``` '0:;<=>?@O[]``^\/' ``` then If condition wll fail and  `@len` will not be decremented then in next loop also same `@random` value will be used and same `@char` will be generated so it is going for infinite loop.

Move the initialization of `@random` variable inside `while` loop to generate new random value in each loop.

```
DECLARE @random DECIMAL(18,18) 

while @len > 0 begin
    SELECT @random =  dbo.RandFn()
    select @char = char(round(@random * 74 + 48, 0))

    if charindex(@char, @exclude) = 0 begin
        set @output = @output + @char
        set @len = @len - 1
    end
end
```

Comment: This is close but its only updating the column to include 1 char instead of a  whole 'string'.

Comment: I think something else is going on here. It just ran for 14mins with no sign of stopping. I only have 82 records that I'm updating so it can't honestly take that long can it?

Comment: Thank you! I got it working actually. Had to set the "ALTER FUNCTION generateString() RETURNS VARCHAR" to "RETURNS VARCHAR(50)" as well so that when I use the function in my update statement, it gives me more than just one character.